# Как спарсить текст имеющий спецсимвол &nbsp; из html при помощи python + bs4

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Купили более 3200 раз

Нужно достать отсюда "Купили 3200 раз", но при попытке это сделать, вытаскивается просто "Купили", всё из-за спец.символа.Его как-то можно обойти?
Мой код:
reviews = soup.find("span", class_="j-orders-count").get_text()

Comment: скиньте ссылку на страницу

Comment: Извиняюсь, html в страницу вписался вот код html^

Comment: <p class="order-quantity j-orders-count-wrapper">Купили <span class="j-orders-count">более 3200&nbsp;раз</span></p>

Comment: https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/6426072/detail.aspx?targetUrl=ES

Comment: Через selenium вытаскивается нормально, но не хочется его запускать ради одного параметра

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно указали условие. Ваше число 3200 хранится в переменной ordertCount, ниже представлен скрипт, который вытаскивает эту переменную

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from re import search
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/6426072/detail.aspx?targetUrl=ES')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

js_script = soup.find_all('script')
matchs = search(r'"ordersCount":[0-9]{1,5}', str(js_script[20]))

orderCount = matchs.group()
print(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, orderCount)))
```

Output:
3200

Comment: print(r.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Вот отсюда https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/6426072/detail.aspx?targetUrl=ES

Comment: HELP PLEASE HELP

Comment: Ответ изменил, в следующий раз, пожалуйста, указывайте условие точнее

Comment: Спасибо!Извиняюсь что не сказал условие сразу, огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Без проблем, поставьте галочку рядом с ответом, пожалуйста, если он вам помог.