# Вопрос по python и beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python, css, парсер, beautiful-soup

Парсю сайт, магазин. Там графа "покупки за последние 2 месяца", я ее парсю с помощью селекторов. В коде элемента страницы написано так
`<span class="j-orders-count">более 1300&nbsp;раз</span>`
Т.е. текст более 1300 раз написан, но когда я спарсиваю, мне выводит

```
<span class="j-orders-count"></span>
```

Т.е. без текста, что мне делать?

Comment: Вы второй человек за последние полчаса, который парсит wildberries. Это задание с курса какого-то?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144311/Как-спарсить-текст-имеющий-спецсимвол-nbsp-из-html-при-помощи-python-bs4

Comment: @JackWolf ну я незнаю где он это нашел, но я бродил по просторам kwork, не брать заказ, а так, попрактиковаться, там нужно было три магазина парсить, я решил один. Кстати спасибо